# Incrementing millisUntilFinished (Countdowntimer) - Android

Tags: android, increment, countdowntimer

While onTick how can I increment the timer, tried various things but they all just start a new timer. I want to increment it as it goes along e.g.

Time left :5 sec

```
"on_Press_Some_Button();"
millisUntilFinished+=2000
```

Time left :7 sec

Comment: Can you explain a little better? There is no `onIncrement()` for `CountDownTimer`. It is a "count down" not a "count up". You certainly can increment some variable in `onTick()` if you want. Otherwise, you may want to use something else depending on exactly what you want. Maybe a `while loop` that increments a variable and stops when you want...

Comment: `"on_Press_Some_Button"` i want `millisUntilFinished+=3000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will go for a different approach based on wrapping the CountdownTimer itself.

```
public abstract class MyCountDownTimer {

    private CountDownTimer cdt;
    private long millisInFuture;
    private long countDownInterval;

    public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        this.millisInFuture = millisInFuture;
        this.countDownInterval = countDownInterval;

        recreateCounter(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    public abstract void onFinish();

    public abstract void onTick(long millisUntilFinished);

    public void start(){
        cdt.start();
    }

    private void setMillisInFuture(long millisInFuture){
        this.millisInFuture = millisInFuture;
    }

    public void onIncrement(long millis){
        millisInFuture += millis;
        recreateCounter(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    private void recreateCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval){
        if(cdt != null){
            try {
                cdt.cancel();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        cdt = new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                setMillisInFuture(millisUntilFinished);
                MyCountDownTimer.this.onTick(millisUntilFinished);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                MyCountDownTimer.this.onFinish();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Hope it suits your needs!

Comment: If i am not wrong there is some incomplete code above, but after completing that it works properly.
Following is the change in onIncrement(long millis) : 
     public void onIncrement(long millis){
        millisInFuture += millis;
        recreateCounter(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        cdt.start()
    }

Also, a wrapper method for cancel() will help : 
    public void cancel() {
        cdt.cancel();
    }

Answer (score 0):

if you need something to happen every x millis, you could use TimerTask as such:

```
    time = 0;
    //Declare the timer
    t = new Timer();
    //Set the schedule function and rate
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
    {

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
            {

                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                           //do what u need to
                    }

            });
        }

    },
    //Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
    0,
    //Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
    1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CountDownTimer count = new CountDownTimer(1000000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                // this will decrement 100 to 1
                int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 100;

                int minutes = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
                int hours = (int) (((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60)) % 60))%60;

                // this will increment 1 to 100
                int incrementSeconds = 100 - seconds;

            }

            public void onFinish() {
            }
        };

        count.start();
```